# MVC Enums and Models in one View - Error: "is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, model-view

I'm trying to use the model getting passed in the controller and an Enum in my view. I keep getting an error that the type is not valid in the given context. I am trying to use an extension method to get the display value from the enum. The model getting passed is a DB model, therefore I don't want to add the enum to the model.

This is a partial of the View:

```
@model Domain.Models.Customer
@using Domain.Enums


             @using (Html.BeginForm("CustomerEdit", "Customer", null, FormMethod.Post, false, null)) {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Idcustomer)
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Customer Name")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.Name, new { @class="form-control"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeZoneAdjustment, "Time Zone Adjustment")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.TimeZoneAdjustment, new { @type="number", @class="form-control"})
                    </div>
                </div>   
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IndividualRegistrationProvider, "Individual Registration Provider")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <select class="form-control" id="@Html.IdFor(model => model.IndividualRegistrationProvider)">
                            <option selected>Select Individual Provider</option>
                            @foreach (var provider in RegistrationProviders)
                            {
                              <option value="@provider.GetDescription()">@provider.GetDescription()</option>
                            }
                        </select>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            }
```

The error is showing on the following div but it's complaining about the enum.

I tried

@using Domain.Enums

@using RegistrationEnum = Domain.Enums.RegistrationProviders

and I also tried

@foreach (var provider in  Domain.Enums.RegistrationProviders)

Enum Code:

```
namespace Domain.Enums
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Text;

    public enum RegistrationProviders
    {
        [Description("Team")]
        Team,

        [Description("Play")]
        Play,

        [Description("Blue Star")]
        BlueStar,

        [Description("Other")]
        Other,

        [Description("None")]
        None
    }
}
```

Extension Code:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumValue) where T: struct, IConvertible
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var description = enumValue.ToString();
            var fieldInfo = enumValue.GetType().GetField(description);

            if(fieldInfo != null)
            {
                var attrs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);

                if(attrs?.Length > 0)
                {
                    description = ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
                }
            }

            return description;
        }
    }
```

Comment: which line causing error?

Comment: The error is coming from the enum. It show on a different line but its complaining about the enum.

Comment: But posted code, you have just declared enum, not used anywhere

Comment: `@using` is used to either reference a namespace or a type in a static context. Just referencing a type without giving it an alias is not valid.  So you want either `@using Domain` or `@using Enums=Domain.Enums`

Comment: @JEuvin is `Domain.Enums` the namespace of enum? Can you please show us your enum code

Comment: @viveknuna I am using the enum in the for loop. I posted the enum code as well.

Comment: @DStanley I posted the three different ways I have tried using the declaration of the enum. All 3 fail.

Comment: @JEuvin where is this method defined `GetDescription` , it shouldn't be called this way

Comment: @viveknuna I posted the code for the extension method. Even if I take out the call to the extension method it still throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `foreach` loop like this.

```
@foreach(RegistrationProviders provider in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RegistrationProviders)))
{

}
```

Comment: This doesn't get me the descriptions. That's why I didn't do it this way.

Comment: Why do you need it generic? why `where T: struct` why not `where T: enum` ?

Comment: I really don't I just made it generic in case we may want to expand on this at a latter time.

Comment: I needed to add  @using Domain.Extensions to the View to get the extension to work.

Comment: @JEuvin glad to know that it’s working for you

Comment: Thank you Vivek.